# Android PWA - how to prevent reloading after switch between apps?

Tags: android, angular, progressive-web-apps

If we have cheap Android phone with lack of resources, when several apps are opened and you switch between them - each one is being loaded again (because device doesn't have enough memory to keep them all alive in background).

When using PWA this may be very annoying. For example I fill some fields in my PWA and have to switch to mail app to copy some data. After returning to PWA it's refreshing (and taking some time to become interactive again)...

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour and keep PWA always alive even when switching to other apps?

Comment: Facing the same issue. Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Still no solution. Refresh may occur even when some input field is focused... Otherwise there could be a solution :)